# How to set Date and time from UIDatePicker to UITextField in 12 hours format

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, datepicker, dateformatter

If system date is in 24 hours format. I want to set selected date and time in 12 hours format with AM/PM to textfield as input view. I am trying to convert selected date and time but its giving me 24 hours format. Can anyone please help me. Here is my code for conversion:

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    let dateAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
    let DateIn12 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    print("12 hour formatted Date:", DateIn12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing unnecessary work here.

Given you already have a date, this should work:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
let date12 = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
print("12 hour formatted Date:", date12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date in any format you want from the date picker's date value.
Here are a couple of options that might help.

```
let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
var dateAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
print(dateAsString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-yy-dd HH:mm"
dateAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
print(dateAsString)
```

This gives

```
2017-09-18 1:18 PM
Sep-17-18 13:18
```

You should not need the second half of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass datepickerview.date in dateformatter. 
try this

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
print("Date:=\(datePickerView.date)")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"
let DateIn12 = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)  
print("12 hour formatted Date:", DateIn12)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my system date is 24 hours and when I print the time Date12 its giving 24 hours time. I need time in 12 hours.

Comment: @user2586519 You can try now with my updated answer, hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"

To get time in 24 hours format uppercased "H" is used in the formatter
while lowercased "h" gives you the time in 12 hour format.

So you can create the dateformatter everytime on your own keeping this in mind.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code to convert 24 hour date into 12 hour format with following code

```
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
    //Formatter "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a" for 24 hours time
    // "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a" for 12 hours time
    // So you need to write only
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    let twelveHourDate = formatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
    print("12 hour format date is \(twelveHourDate)")
```

Comment: I don't know why you people down vote the answer. To give this answer I have implement and test this method in play ground on my own (which takes time), I did my best to give the answer as I see the question, I don't know how are you deciding that this is repeat , Bro all the correct answer will  similar to each other. So if my answer is  repeat than except one answer all are repeated because all have given the same answere. Conclusion : Please don't down vote if you can't upvote , I have n't cheated this answere from anywhere else I write it own my own.